# Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x300

Tags: c++, pocketsphinx

I am trying to compile my code including pocketsphinx which needs a dll file to compile. I have tried using both a .dll and .lib file but I get this error.

```
Error   LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x300
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does fatal error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'" occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133698/why-does-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-c-program-obj-occur-when-i-c)

Comment: That didn't help. I now get this error:
Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x300

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lib and DLL linking to an exe confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599539/lib-and-dll-linking-to-an-exe-confusion)

Comment: Agreed. Until you posted that I did not notice the OP was trying to link to the `dll` instead of the `lib`.

Comment: You should not get this same error if you link to the `.lib` and remove any link to the `.dll`. Since this is an x64 binary make sure you are creating a 64 bit application.

Comment: When I use the lib files I get: Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _cmd_ln_init referenced in function _main
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ps_args referenced in function _main